# Ubuntu Server v23.10 Reboot Issue

Tags: shutdown, reboot, 23.10

I've installed a new Ubuntu Server v23.10 (running headless, without screen/keyboard)
When i try to reboot the server the system does not restart ( using "shutdown -r now" or "reboot" )
It just waits for me to press the powerbutton

Strangly when i connect a keyboard to the system, the reboot works fine

I tried loading the modules hid, usbhid and hid_generic manually, but without success

Does anyone have a hint on how to fix this ?

```
root@ubuntuserver:~# journalctl -b -1 -e
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounted snap-gnome\x2b44\x2b4404-141.mount - Mount unit for gnome-42-2204, revision 141.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounted snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount - Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1535.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: snap-lxd-25846.mount: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounted snap-lxd-25846.mount - Mount unit for lxd, revision 25846.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: snap-lxd-26200.mount: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounted snap-lxd-26200.mount - Mount unit for lxd, revision 26200.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: snap-snapd-20290.mount: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounted snap-snapd-20290.mount - Mount unit for snapd, revision 20290.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: snap-snapd-20671.mount: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounted snap-snapd-20671.mount - Mount unit for snapd, revision 20671.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped target snapd.mounts-pre.target - Mounting snaps.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounting boot.mount - /boot...
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounting run-snapd-ns.mount - /run/snapd/ns...
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounting snap.mount - Ensure that the snap directory shares mount events....
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-EAD6\x2dFE46.service: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-EAD6\x2dFE46.service - File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/EAD6-FE46.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d405a30c\x2d79bb\x2d4a00\x2dafb3\x2df1d02f5cb248.service: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d405a30c\x2d79bb\x2d4a00\x2dafb3\x2df1d02f5cb248.service - File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/d405a30c-79bb-4a00-afb>
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver kernel: EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): unmounting filesystem cffb030ce-806a-4312-bd69-abc345d0a404.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: run-snapd-ns.mount: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounted run-snapd-ns.mount - /run/snapd/ns.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: boot.mount: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounted boot.mount - /boot.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped target swap.target - Swaps.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Deactivating swap swap.img.swap - /swap.img...
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-cffb030ce\x2d806a\x2d4312\x2dbd69\x2abce345d0a404.service: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-cffb030ce\x2d806a\x2d4312\x2dbd69\x2abce345d0a404.service - File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/cffb030ce-806a-4312-bd6>
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice - Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: snap.mount: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Unmounted snap.mount - Ensure that the snap directory shares mount events..
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped target local-fs-pre.target - Preparation for Local File Systems.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopping lvm2-monitor.service - Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver multipathd[491]: multipathd: shut down
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopping multipathd.service - Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller...
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service - Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-sysusers.service - Create System Users.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: swap.img.swap: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Deactivated swap swap.img.swap - /swap.img.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Reached target umount.target - Unmount All Filesystems.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: multipathd.service: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver lvm[5684]:   1 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" unmonitored
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped multipathd.service - Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-remount-fs.service - Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: lvm2-monitor.service: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Stopped lvm2-monitor.service - Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Reached target shutdown.target - System Shutdown.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Reached target final.target - Late Shutdown Services.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: systemd-reboot.service: Deactivated successfully.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Finished systemd-reboot.service - System Reboot.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Reached target reboot.target - System Reboot.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Shutting down.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd-journald[456]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
feb 09 13:11:31 ubuntuserver systemd-journald[456]: Journal stopped
```

Comment: Does it reboot properly if you do `sudo bash -c 'sync; echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger'; sleep 1; sync; sleep 1; reboot -f`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the command, but unfortunately is has the same result as a normal reboot

Comment: Have you tried the `reboot=pci` kernel command line parameter?

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effect.                

Tried    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="reboot=pci"
/ And      GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force reboot=acpi"

After some reading i found:
kbd    Use the keyboard controller. cold reset (default)

Comment: What about `reboot=triple`?

Comment: also tried reboot=bios (also has no effect)

Comment: If `reboot=triple` don't work, then your ACPI/BIOS firmware has a problem. triple literally tells the CPU itself to restart

Comment: The reboot=triple did not work ..

Comment: It appears adding to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT has no effect, i'll try to hook up a display and try adding it manually

Comment: Did you remember to do `update-grub`?

Comment: Yes, update-grub after every change and tried at least 2 reboots with every variant

Comment: I hooked up a monitor and antered the reboot=pci kernel parameter manually. But without a keyboard attached to te systemen it won't reboot.